# SQL command to update (replace) a fixed text value by another one

Tags: sql, sql-update, hana

I have to update a value in one field of a table (t1).

Current table t1 records :

```
| POLNAME  | VALUE  |
|-------------------|
| TEST_01  | Normal |
| TEST_02  | High   |
| TEST_03  | Normal |
| TEST_04  | Low    |
| TEST_05  | Low**  |
```

New table t1 records expected after the update :

```
| POLNAME  | VALUE  |
|-------------------|
| REST_01  | Normal |
| REST_02  | High   |
| REST_03  | Normal |
| REST_04  | Low    |
| REST_05  | Low**  |
```

I need to replace, in t1-POLNAME field, the fixed value 'TEST_' by 'REST_' for all records of table t1.

I can do one by one using an UPDATE SQL command, but my goal is to replace all records using one SQL command.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [REPLACE SQL FUNCTION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms186862.aspx).

```
UPDATE t1 SET POLNAME=REPLACE(POLNAME, 'TEST','REST');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [REPLACE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html)

UPDATE `t1` SET `POLNAME`=REPLACE(`POLNAME`, 'TEST','REST');